# How to filter specific details in an output Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

So i want to export all my AD groups and the members inside of it in a clean list.

I used the basic command :

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties * | select CN,members
```

which almost gave me what i want but the members property also gives the OU and DC of every member, I was wondering if it is possible to change the output from

```
CN                   members 
--                   -------                  
Name of The Group    CN=Name of the User,OU=User Groups,OU=User,DC=DOMAIN,DC=com
```

to

```
CN                   members                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
--                   -------                                                                  
Name of the Group    User1, User2, User3
```

Or even keeping the `CN=`

Is it possible to filter out every OU and DC?
Sorry i don't really know how to format on this website

Comment: Are you sure you want the object name, and not some unique value instead (like their username)?

Comment: As long as i can differentiate my users when i use the command it's fine, i tried using the get-ADgroupMember Cmd but it was messier, 
Instead of having Group > Every member in it, it had a line for each user and each group which isn't all that bad but not practical.

Comment: When you say "line", what is the end game here? Do you want to export the data to a CSV file or similar?

Comment: Yes to keep track of who is in what group with an easier visibility than manually in the AD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need details of the members, you may need additional calls to AD

I recommend to retrieve only those properties you need, so you can minimize the traffic. Instead

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties *
```

I suggest

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties members
```

To iterate and get the members details, for example DisplayName. Be aware that some key properties are always returned

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties members | 
Select -ExpandProperty member |% {
  Get-ADUser -Id $_ -Properties "Displayname" 
}
```

I you want to export the list to a csv or excel, can be better export in a plain list instead Group, ListOfUsers. The final script can be something like

```
$groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties members
foreach ($group in $groups) {
    foreach($member in $members) {
        $user = Get-ADUser -Id $member -Properties DisplayName
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Group = $group.Name
            UserName = $user.UserPrincipalName
            User = $userDisplayName
        }
    }
}
```

you will a list like:

```
Group       userName              User
-----       --------              ----
GroupA      User1@domain.com      User 1
GroupA      User2@domain.com      User 2
GroupA      User3@domain.com      User 3
GroupB      User1@domain.com      User 1
GroupB      User4@domain.com      User 4
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i adapted what you gave and i got the same result, thanks for the help